# Parsing range request header with logstah

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I need to parse a range request value into start_range and end_range in logstash. The data comes from a json object and looks like this:

```
byte_range: "bytes=10-200"
```

and I want to extract start and end into separate values like this:

```
start_range:10
end_range:200
```

I also need to take into account that the value could look like this:

```
byte_range: "bytes=10-"
```

and should still result in:

```
start_range: 10
end_range: -
```

I tried doing it like this with a grok filter but it does not work:

```
bytes=%{NUMBER:start_range}-%{NUMBER:end_range}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this as simple as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an optional non-capturing group `(?:...)?`:

```
bytes=(?<start_range>\d+)(?:-(?<end_range>\d+))?
```

where `\d+` matches 1+ digits.

Or using the built-in Grok patterns:

```
bytes=%{INT:start_range}(?:-%{INT:end_range})?
```